# Is dead state only linked with the final state in any automata?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am very much new to this subject and as far as I have tried the small research I found this most meaningful at [this](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Automata_theory/Finite_automata) link

> **Dead State** - A rejecting state that is essentially a dead end. Once
>   the machine enters a dead state, there is no way for it to reach an
>   accepting state, so we already know that the string is going to be
>   rejected. Graphically, the dead state is often omitted and assumed for
>   any input that the machine does not have explicit instructions on what
>   to do with. A machine may have multiple dead states, but at most only
>   one dead state is needed per machine.

Now I am designing a what is very simple machine for my homework and the question is that part in the definition

> ......*that string is often omitted*....

so what should I do for a machine that says that

> **L1 = {Strings starting with “a” over ∑ = {a,b} }**

Now I know that this will be a very simple machine that will move towards final state if it starts with a and stays in final state over any new comer so the real question should I add the **Dead State**   here, because the definition is saying that

> **dead state is often omitted and assumed for any input that the machine**
>   **doesn't have explicit instructions on what to do with**

, that can move the automaton to the dead state in case the first letter is not a and so that dead stays lock the machine to that dead state.
Considering my question L1 should I mention dead state or just leave it assumed.

*Sorry for bad reformatting and confusing statements I am very new to the course*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that since you’re just beginning, it would be best to include the dead state in your graphical description of the automaton. (Indeed, some instructors will require you to do so.) You need to include it in the full symbolic description anyway, and the automaton is so simple that including it in the graph doesn’t really add any clutter: even with the dead state it has only three states altogether.

To answer the question in your title, the dead state has transitions only **to** itself, but it may have transitions **from** many states, some of them final (acceptor) states and some not.

Comment: so it means that it is ok to skip the dead state in conditions like mine **L1** where the dead state is eminent for the dead state

Comment: @DevX: Not quite. Suppose that $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, as in your exercise. The full graph of a DFA will have an $a$-transition and a $b$-transition out of each state node. What it’s saying is that if the DFA has a dead state, many people consider it acceptable to omit the dead state from the graph and all of the transitions into it. This means that when you see a state node $q$ with no $b$-transition out of it, for instance, you mentally add a dead state and a $b$-transition from $q$ to the dead state. But as I said, I think that it’s best when you’re starting to include everything, so that you ...

Comment: ... have an $a$-transition and a $b$-transition out of every node. For one thing, this is something that’s easy to check, and checking it helps to make sure that you really do have a DFA.